# scala case class initialisation

Tags: scala, class, case

Below is my case classes. How to initialise case class child in scala?

```
// case class 
case class parent(id: String, name: String, rNo: Int,
                  child: Option[Child])

case class Child(cid: String, Ctype: String,
                 group_category_id: String,
                 unlock_at: String, due_at: String)

val a: Child = if (x.child != None) { x.child.get } else { null }
```

If I declare as null, it will throw `NullPointerException` in case of else condition. How to solve that?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should unwrap the `Option[Child]` so that it would be `null` if it was empty. You shouldn't use nulls when you write idiomatic Scala. I would keep it in an `Option` and use the `map` and `flatMap` methods on it, to access the child if it exists.

However, if you really want to, you can do it like this:

```
val a: Child = x.child.getOrElse(null)
```

Comment: When i am mapping case classes to Json Response , Child value is not always present, sometime it is, sometime not. Also i need to fetch fields present in Child class, in that case it will throw null pointer exception ,Right? i need to access  **a.grading_type**

Comment: No You don't. That why Option class is form. You might have value or not. A null is not welcome in functional programming. Options gives you information that the value may missing in some cases.

Comment: Do this: `val gradingType: Option[String] = x.child.map(_.grading_type)`

Comment: suppose gradingType is null                  if(gradingType.toString() !=null) {   }         , here if condition fail right?

Comment: Instead of `if(gradingType != null) { // Do something }`, do this: `gradingType.map(gType => // Do something )`. Here, `gType` will be the actual string, and `// Do something` will only happen if the `Option` is a `Some` (which means that a value is present). If you see yourself using `null` in Scala, you're doing it wrong. Why do you call the `toString` method?

Comment: @marstran that is wrong too. it is not `//Do something`it is `//transform`.
`.foreach{_.grading_type => //Do something }` is right for just "use" the value.

Comment: I meant that, or else I would have used `foreach`. What I write in a comment is insignificant. Also, `foreach` requires a side-effect to do something. You don't want that when doing functional programming.